# Intellij has a problem with scalafmt and scala 3

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, scalafmt

my .scalafmt.conf file content is:

```
version = 3.5.4
```

Intellij downloaded scalafmt for this version:

[image]

but when I want to format file I have error saying literally nothing:

[image]

IntelliJ Version:

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2022.1.1 (Community Edition)
Build #IC-221.5591.52, built on May 10, 2022
```

Any ideas how to solve this issue ?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should explicitly specify `runner.dialect` 
In case of Scala 3 add `runner.dialect = scala3` 
See https://scalameta.org/scalafmt/docs/configuration.html#scala-dialects

As for non-descriptive error message see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-20123